# React Material UI - Change Stepper text color

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How do you change the text color inside of the stepper? I want the text 3 to be in black color instead of white : [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mHOl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to add this to your `index.css` file (or any other root css file you have in your project):

```css
.MuiStepIcon-text {
    fill: black !important; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! You just missed the important tag.